# Using UIView.transition(from, to) with autoLayout constraints

Tags: swift, autolayout

I am trying to show a card and flip that card on tap.

For this I have a UIView which acts as a container view for two separate UIViews (frontView, backView). I have attached a tapGestureRecognizer to the container view and am calling the function below.

```
@objc func flipCard() {
    print("Flipping card")

    if showingBack == true {
        UIView.transition(from: backView, to: frontView, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, completion: nil)
        showingBack = false
    } else {
        UIView.transition(from: frontView, to: backView, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromRight, completion: nil)
        showingBack = true
    }
}
```

The first flip works, flipping back doesn't work - the card simply disappears. I was able to figure out that as soon as I set AutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to true for those two sub views, the flipping works just fine, like this:

```
@objc func flipCard() {
    print("Flipping card")
    frontView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    backView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

    if showingBack == true {
        UIView.transition(from: backView, to: frontView, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, completion: nil)
        showingBack = false
    } else {
        UIView.transition(from: frontView, to: backView, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromRight, completion: nil)
        showingBack = true
    }
}
```

However, setting the AutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to true causes a few UI collisions in my view which is why I'd like to avoid that. I'm grateful for tips how I can work around this. And can someone explain why exactly this is happening in the first place?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is giving you problem, try with this:

```
@objc func flipCard() {
    print("Flipping card")
    frontView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    backView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

    if showingBack == true {
        UIView.transition(from: backView, to: frontView, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft) { (success) in
            frontView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            backView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            showingBack = false
        }
    } else {
        UIView.transition(from: frontView, to: backView, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionFlipFromRight) { (success) in
            frontView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            backView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            showingBack = true
        }
    }
}
```

if `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true` means that
the system creates a set of constraints that duplicate the behaviour specified by the view’s autoresizing mask. When it is false means are being used pure constraints (`NSLayoutConstraint`).

Moreover, please note that:

> By default, the property is set to true for any view you
>   programmatically create. If you add views in Interface Builder, the
>   system automatically sets this property to false.

Comment: Glad you found it useful :)

Answer (score 3):

I have a constantly flipping `UIView` container that uses `false`. What I do is deal with the `options` parameter differently, adding `.showHideTransitionViews` to the direction of the flip. Without this, I just had it flip once and then... nothing.

It's kind of odd because you can't "just" add it (at least in Swift 3 iOS 10 days), but here's what you might try:

```
let flipFromLeftOptions: UIViewAnimationOptions = [.transitionFlipFromLeft, .showHideTransitionViews]
let flipFromRightOptions: UIViewAnimationOptions = [.transitionFlipFromRight, .showHideTransitionViews]
```

And in the transition code:

```
if showingBack == true {
    UIView.transition(from: backView, to: frontView, duration: 0.3, options: flipFromLeftOptions, completion: nil)
    showingBack = false
} else {
    UIView.transition(from: frontView, to: backView, duration: 0.3, options: flipFromRightOptions, completion: nil)
    showingBack = true
}
```

Comment: Thanks @dfd.  Exactly what I needed!